# Android : Extract article main content. How to extract content img only and remove icon img

Tags: android, image, textview, imageview, jsoup

I am using JSoup libray to extract the text elements and display them in a `TextView` and display the images in a `ImageView` using `ImageLoader`. `ImageLoader` is a class that I created to load and cache images. My following code successfully displays text and image. However, I just want to display img in the main content. May I know how can I remove all the icon img? The following is my code.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    setContentToView();
}

public void setContentToView(){
    List<String> p = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> src = new ArrayList<>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
    Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();
    String body;

    for(Element element :elements ){
        Tag tag = element.tag();
        if(tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("p") ){
            element.select("img").remove();
            body= element.html() + "<br>";
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(body));
            this.linearLayout.addView(textView);
            p.add(body);
        }


        if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("img")){
            String url  = element.select("img").attr("src");
            String urls = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com"+ url;
            int loader = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
            imgLoader.DisplayImage(urls, loader, imageView);
            this.linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            src.add(urls);
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the result of code. But I want to remove all unnecessary icon img.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove all unnecessary icon img.

Before extracting data, remove the div containing the icon img (see the sample code below)

#### SAMPLE

```
String url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/joomla/joomla_control_panel.htm";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
System.out.println("BEFORE: " + doc.select("img[src$=Icon.jpg]").size());

doc.select("#rightbar").remove();
System.out.println("AFTER: " + doc.select("img[src$=Icon.jpg]").size());
```

#### OUTPUT

```
BEFORE: 5
AFTER: 0
```

---

One last note, the code is trying to resolve img urls. Jsoup can do it. So instead of:

```
String url  = element.select("img").attr("src");
String urls = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com"+ url;
```

use this:

```
String urls  = element.absUrl("src"); // Jsoup will construct the absolute url for you
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But icon still displaying.

Comment: @JackChan Can you precise what you call "icon" please ?Can you post your url?

Comment: "Icon" refers to facebook, google plus icon and etc as shown in picture above. This is the url link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/joomla/joomla_control_panel.htm. Between that I have an idea to remove all the unnecessary icon picture, we remove all the picture after <a tag. Because icon picture always provide link to other page. Can we just remove all the <img after <a tag in Jsoup?

Comment: @JackChan Please see my update with a small snippet demonstrating how to remove the icons.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks, problem solved. May I know can I remove header banner picture also?